# RestTemplate, проблемы с postForObject

Tags: java, post, юнит-тесты, test-automation, resttemplate

Я хочу написать тест для веб-приложения, где создаю нового юзера и добавляю его с помощью `postForObject`, но `id` передается не тот, который нужно, причём с каждым следующим запуском этого теста он увеличивается. Таким образом я не могу добавить юзера с заданным `id`, так как он меняется.

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
UserDTO ivan = new UserDTO(5, "ivan", "ivanov");
UserDTO result = restTemplate.postForObject(BASE_USERS, ivan, UserDTO.class);
assertThat(result, notNullValue());
assertEquals(ivan.getId(), result.getId());
restTemplate.delete(BASE_USERS + "/" + result.getId());
```

[image: первая итерация]

[image: следующая]

Может кто-то может объяснить, почему так происходит, с чем это связано, и сделать так, чтобы я могла добавить юзера с `id`, который мне нужен?

Comment: я так понимаю, что это тест. а какой метод вы пытаетесь таким образом протестировать(добавляйте его, если он существует в природе)? или вы прямо сам спринговый RestTemplate  хотите тестить (тогда это задача не ваша, пусть на него разработчики спринга тесты пишут). а заодно спрошу : вы про моки слышали?

Answer (score 0):

Эта проблема никак не связана с `RestTemplate`.

Очевидно, что при создании пользователя с помощью метода API, который находится по URL `BASE_USERS`, поле `id`, которое передается в запросе, игнорируется, и происходит автоматическая генерация этого поля (каждый новый пользователь автоматически получает `id` на единичку больше чем предыдущий).

Если ваша задача — протестировать готовый метод, который уже реализован, в соответствии с требованиями, а именно, что происходит автоматическая генерация идентификатора, то нужно адаптировать тест так, чтобы он проверял это требование.

Не нужно передавать `id` и с ним сравнивать. Нужно проверить, что:

1. идентификатор действительно генерируется (т.е. он непустой)
2. сгенерированный идентификатор можно использовать для доступа к пользователю по `id` (если есть такой метод в API)
3. что генерируется уникальный идентификатор, т.е. при двух вызовах метода генерируются отличающиеся идентификаторы
4. что в других полях пользователя значение те, которые были переданы при создании

Этого должно быть достаточно для тестирования данного функционала (в данном случае end to end, к сожалению, не знаю хорошего русского термина).

Если же требование звучит так, что этот метод должен использовать `id` из запроса, то нужно исправлять его реализацию.